# How to scrape data from linkedin my network connection?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

How to scrape data from linkedin my network connection?
I have succesfully scraped the Name of pereson from single url https://www.linkedin.com/in/$yourfriendname/

Is there any way to scrape from
https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import getpass
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pprint

chrome_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com")
userid='xxxx@gmail.com'
password = ('xxxxxxxx')
driver.implicitly_wait(6)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login- 
email"]""").send_keys(userid)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login- 
password"]""").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login-submit"]""").click()
url='www.linkedin.com/in/$yourfriendname/'  
driver.get("https://"+url.rstrip())
connectionName = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pv-top-card- 
section__name').get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(connectionName)

>>YOUR FRIEND NAME

url1='https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/'
driver.get(url1.rstrip())
```

### How to scrape from above url1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for extracing the href tags

```
url1='https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/'
driver.get(url1.rstrip())
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mn-connection-card__details']//a[@data-control-name='connection_profile'][@href]")

for elem in elems:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    print (elem.get_attribute("href"))
```